# UITableview with cell two cells

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to use the DeviceTableViewCell classics together with TDBadgedCell. How do we use the two clans together? For example, your cellBadgedCell class .I want to use badgeString with the cell class. It'il be the way I showed it in the code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {    
    return items.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cellBadgedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"BadgedCell") as? TDBadgedCell;

    if(cellBadgedCell == nil) {
        cellBadgedCell = TDBadgedCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "BadgedCell");
    }

    cellBadgedCell?.badgeString = demoItems[indexPath.row]["badge"]! 
    cellBadgedCell.badgeColor = .orange

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

The function I want should be like this:

```
cell?.badgeString = ıtems[indexPath.row]["badge"]!
cell.badgeColor = .orange
```

Comment: Which cell you are returning?  `cellBadgedCell ` or  `cell `?

Comment: Only One cell must be return. Please check here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview

Comment: I'm dialing 'return cell'

Comment: ok then only "DeviceTableViewCell" will be returned

Comment: I don't understand? I just want to "cell.badgeColor = .orange How do I write? He's making a mistake when I do that.

Comment: You can only pass one cell inside cellForRow indexPath. So do your rendering on selected cell which you want to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you can define 
class DeviceTableViewCell: TDBadgedCell, and you can use badgeString and badgeColor